# GoF Design Patterns - which ones do you actually use?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm trying to educate my colleagues in the area of design patterns.  Some of the original Gang of Four patterns are a little esoteric, so I'm wondering if there is a sub-group of "essential" patterns that all programmers should know. As I look through the list, I think I've probably used -

- Abstract Factory
- Factory Method
- Singleton
- Bridge
- Facade
- Command

Which ones do you actually use in practice, and what do you use them for?

[Link for those wanting a list of patterns](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)

Comment: IMHO, the question is too vague to yield useful discussion. Do you want one answer per pattern or one answer per combination of patterns?

Comment: Some reasons why you use these patterns would be useful, otherwise you're just listing concepts... Imagine asking the question: **"What keywords do you use?"** and gathering lists of "`for, if, while...` etc"  - difficult to measure just how pointless that would be.

Comment: I disagree Slomojo - I think it would be quite handy to know whichi keywords were commonly used and which were not in a language. Same goes for base classes, for example.

Comment: @CraigS I like the direction of the question but you need to make it answerable - in other words, a criteria for answering it other than "what do you use?"

Comment: Ok, modified it a little...

Comment: Modified it a fair bit more - hopefully this will generate some better discussion now.

Comment: Which kinds of fruit do you actually eat?  I'm curious to know what you are hoping to get out of this question.  If you see a pattern that 3 or 4 people have used but you haven't, is that going to make you use it?

Comment: @Marcie - to be frank, this question is driven by a touch of insecurity. Like a lot of people in the MS stream, I came fairly late to the concept of design patterns, and I was self-taught. Now as a manager who is trying to develop his staff, I'm trying to get some real-world input from others, some assurance that we are doing it pretty much the same way as everyone else.

Comment: @CraigS, that's very interesting.  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list of which ones I've used or seen in practice:

Singleton - Application object in ASP.Net being a prime example of this.

Adapter - Connecting to databases usually can involve an Adapter class at least in my area of .Net stuff.

Factory - General for generating objects though I saw this more in some older classic ASP back in the day.

Strategy - I had an application which for each type of device I had a similar structure for the class that I'd consider an implementation of this pattern.

Facade - In some ways this is similar to the Adapter pattern in terms of being something that ties together a couple of systems usually.

Comment: All valid uses. For anyone also reading this - keep in mind that these patterns are certainly not limited to these.

Answer (score 5):

The authors compiled the patterns from observed designs they found in real applications.  No one person will likely use all of them, but they are all used.

Comment: Which has you used smithco, and what for?

Comment: @CraigS I've used many of them.  The authors of Design Patterns have a set of good examples with each pattern they describe.  The best suggest I can give is to spend the time to read the book thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

[Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

**EDIT**: In almost every project that gets beyond the 'trivial' stage, one ends up with an IAction interface (details may differ):

```
// Programming Language does not matter
interface IAction {
     bool operateOn(Foo* target);
     string getDisplayName(); // useful for debugging and logging
};
```

The next hour I spend on writing a lot of small, almost trivial classes that implement IAction. When combined, they are very powerful and flexible.

E.g. an `LogAction` (write to log and perform the IAction), `NullAction` (do nothing and return true), `ActionList` (perform a list of IActions, and return the ANDing of the bools). In some cases an `AndAction` (return the AND-ing of two actions, could be short-circuited or not), `OrAction`, `NotAction` make sense as well.

Although technically from the examples above only the LogAction is a Decorator (the other do not operate on exactly 1 IAction), I still consider this a generalization of the Decorator pattern when I make a ActionList of LogActions of IActions.

Comment: What do you use it for?

Comment: @CraigS Example added on request.

Comment: It looks more like a mix of Decorator and Composite actually, which is fine, and a perfect demonstration that the difficulty in patterns does not come from using them independently, but from mixing them together :)

Comment: A yes, this is a classic. It is Composite pared with command. There is actually a name for this patten: it's called "Specification" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean to restrict the question to usage of patterns in own code / projects (no class libraries and 3rd party frameworks).

As did others, I have also used the **Factory** patterns most often. Then

- **Singleton**: not so much nowadays, but still sometimes it is necessary, typically for global configuration data
- **Strategy** and **Template Method**: quite often, e.g. for representing different kinds of calculations in our app
- **Builder**: for marshalling the results of transactions with a mainframe system into output objects (in some cases it includes a great deal of text parsing and creating large object hierarchies)
- **Command**: I implemented it only once many years ago, but nowadays in our Java project I use Callables every now and then, which I believe are basically Commands

Answer (score 2):

I've used many of the others which have already been mentioned (Singleton, Factory, Builder, Command, Strategy, etc...)

One I haven't seen mentioned yet is Flyweight, which I tend to use a lot. I've provided an example implementation below:

```
/**
 * Flyweight class representing OCR digits.
 * 
 * @author matt
 *
 */
public class Digit {
    /** Static flyweight map containing Digits which have been encountered. **/
    private static Map digits = new HashMap();

    /** The block of text representing Digit. **/
    private String blockRep = null;

    /** A map representing acceptable blocks of characters and the string representation of their
     * numerical equivalents.
     */
    public static final Map VALID_DIGITS;

    /** Enum of valid digits. **/
    public static enum DigitRep {
        ZERO    (   " _ \n" +
                    "| |\n" +
                    "|_|"       ),

        ONE (       "   \n" +
                    "  |\n" +
                    "  |"       ),

        TWO (       " _ \n" +
                    " _|\n" +
                    "|_ "       ),

        THREE   (   " _ \n" +
                    " _|\n" +
                    " _|"       ),

        FOUR    (   "   \n" +
                    "|_|\n" +
                    "  |"       ),

        FIVE    (   " _ \n" +
                    "|_ \n" +
                    " _|"       ),

        SIX     (   " _ \n" +
                    "|_ \n" +
                    "|_|"       ),

        SEVEN   (   " _ \n" +
                    "  |\n" +
                    "  |"       ),

        EIGHT   (   " _ \n" +
                    "|_|\n" +
                    "|_|"       ),

        NINE    (   " _ \n" +
                    "|_|\n" +
                    " _|"       );

        private String blockRep;

        DigitRep(String blockRep) {
            this.blockRep = blockRep;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return blockRep;
        }
    }

    static {
        /* Initialize the map of acceptable character blocks. */
        Map tmpMap = new HashMap();
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.ZERO.toString(),   "0");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.ONE.toString(),    "1");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.TWO.toString(),    "2");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.THREE.toString(),  "3");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.FOUR.toString(),   "4");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.FIVE.toString(),   "5");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.SIX.toString(),    "6");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.SEVEN.toString(),  "7");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.EIGHT.toString(),  "8");
        tmpMap.put( DigitRep.NINE.toString(),   "9");       
        VALID_DIGITS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmpMap);
    }

    /**
     * Private constructor to enforce flyweight/factory pattern.
     * 
     * @param blockRep
     */
    private Digit(String blockRep) {
        this.blockRep = blockRep;
    }

    /**
     * Flyweight factory method to create a Digit object from the "block"
     * representation of the digit.
     * @param blockRep The "block" representation of a digit.  Should look
     * something like:
     * " _ \n"
     * "|_|\n"
     * "|_|"
     * @return A flyweight Digit object representing the digit.
     */
    public static synchronized Digit getDigit(String blockRep) {
        Digit digit = digits.get(blockRep);
        if(digit == null) {
            digit = new Digit(blockRep);
            digits.put(blockRep, digit);
        }

        return digit;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether or not the digit is valid.
     * @return true if the digit is valid, else false.
     */
    public boolean isValid() {
        return VALID_DIGITS.containsKey(blockRep);
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method to get the block representation of this digit.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getBlockRep() {
        return blockRep;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return VALID_DIGITS.containsKey(blockRep) ? VALID_DIGITS.get(blockRep) : "?";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 one of the lesser known but still incredibly useful patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the original Gang of Four patterns are still used today, but there are other now popular ones that aren't in the book.

Find a reference for Design Patters in the language you use. They tend to be more concrete and use specific language features to implement the patterns in a more succinct and elegant way.

Three great resources for Design Patterns:

["Head First Design Patterns" Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596007124) - the language of choice is Java, but is relevant to all languages.
[dofactory Design Patterns](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) - great and free .net design patterns explanations with code.
[PluralSight - Design Patterns Library](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=patterns-library) - this one is paid, but is too good not to include it in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you use common libraries like ACE, you end up using more than you think you use. I use Observer/Observable extensively :-)

Answer (score 1):

I used a Builder at least once (the same converter process could build HTML or Excel output).

I frequently use the Template Method (for JDBC-related tasks, or abstract Swing controllers).

Once I had to develop lots of new features into a form-based application, which was a mess.
I could only progress after I had refactored the existing stuff to a State-pattern based solution.
(Well, most of it).

I also use Commands frequently (Swing Actions), and Observers too.

Once I used a Mememento-like solution for detecting changes in Swing forms. The form would
serialize its state what I compared (equals()) to earlier states.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have most them thru-out my career. the only one I am sure I have not used is that Adapter Pattern that is implemented with multiple inheritance on the book as I am not a big fan of multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fond of Decorator. The only one I've got add to those mentioned is Proxy.